# mysqlimport: Error: 1452

Tags: mysql, perl, foreign-keys, mysqlimport

I wrote a script in Perl that creates a database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE descType (
    id MEDIUMINT unsigned PRIMARY KEY,
    descr MEDIUMTEXT)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE taxType (
    id MEDIUMINT unsigned PRIMARY KEY,
    descr TEXT not null)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE uniref(
            id INT unsigned PRIMARY KEY,
            seqId varchar (50) not null,
            descId MEDIUMINT unsigned not null,
            n MEDIUMINT unsigned not null,
            taxId MEDIUMINT  unsigned not null,
            repId varchar (50) not null,
            foreign KEY (descId) REFERENCES descType(id),
            FOREIGN KEY (taxId) REFERENCES taxType(id),
            unique(seqId)
            )ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

When I use this command:

```
system qq(mysqlimport -u$mySqlUser -p$mySqlPass $database $table --local --fields-terminated-by="\t" --lines-terminated-by="\r\n") )== 0
   or die "ERROR: an error occurred while importing $table in $database. $?";
```

I get this error:

```
mysqlimport: Error: 1452, Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key 
constraint fails (`uniref_2013_08`.`uniref`, CONSTRAINT `uniref_ibfk_1` 
FOREIGN KEY (`descId`) REFERENCES `descType` (`id`)), when using 
table: uniref
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I was using the same script on another machine and it was working fine.

Comment: Youre missing foreign key in desctype table.

Comment: I read this: "Foreign key relationships involve a parent table that holds the central data values, and a child table with identical values pointing back to its parent. The FOREIGN KEY clause is specified in the child table. The parent and child tables must use the same storage engine. They must not be TEMPORARY tables." This I read on (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). I don't got that I have to write the same foreign key in the parent table. They say that it has to be specified in the child. Actually the child is the uniref table. Am I wrong?

Comment: you want to insert child into `uniref` which references to non-existing parent in `descType`

Comment: I really don't got... I believe to have specified it. Please can you write me what is the correct definition of the tables?

Comment: Definition is ok, but data is not. Foreign key preserves data integrity and prevents insertion if there is no parent row. You need to populate parent table first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreign key preserves data integrity and prevents insertion if there is no parent row. You need to populate `descType` parent table first.